# SSRS - Modify length of multi-value parameters field

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, parameters

I recently upgraded my SSRS 2008 R2 into a 2014 version.

Now, for all my reports using multi-value parameters, I can't modify manually the length of the parameters fields in order to see the entire text of the choices.

In my 2008 R2 version, it was possible with a [cursor at the bottom-right of the drop-down list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdYl6.jpg). But in my 2014 version, this cursor disappeared.

Is this a functional regression? Or is this an option to activate?

[(No problem for the single value parameters due to autogrowth)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GKwwu.jpg)